# Dividir uma coluna em duas a partir de um parâmetro - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Pesquisei uma solução porém não consigo localizar voltada para um data frame, apenas para linhas de input por exemplo.

POSSUO UM DATAFRAME COM OS SEGUINTES CAMPOS E LINHAS:

```
data = {'País': ['Bélgica', 'Índia', 'Brasil'],
'Capital': ['Bruxelas', 'Nova Delhi', 'Brasília'],
'População': ['123/A465', '456/A789', '987/A654']}

df_DIV = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['País','Capital','População'])
```

SAIDA ATUAL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso dividir a coluna População em duas onde o parametro seria a "/" e não há um padrão na quantidade de caracter anterior a '\' para que eu possa dividir com df['Novo_Campo'] = df['População'].str[:5] por exemplo, então precisaria que ficasse dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PORÉM, ESSE É APENAS UM EXEMPLO DO QUE PRECISO FAZER EM UM DF COM MAIS DE 300.000 LINHAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Segue abaixo um exemplo do split para criar novas colunas no df.

```
import pandas as pd 

# Lendo o arquivo CSV e carregando para "data"
data = pd.read_csv("https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/nba.csv") 

# Imprimindo Original no Console
print(data)

# Descartando colunas com valor nulo para evitar erros
data.dropna(inplace = True)

# Nova Data com Split das coluna "Name" separado por espaços
new = data["Name"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)

# Criando a Nova Coluna "First Name" com o new[0]
data["First Name"]= new[0] 

# Criando a Nova Coluna "Last Name" com o new[1]
data["Last Name"]= new[1] 

# Retirando a antiga coluna "Name" 
data.drop(columns =["Name"], inplace = True) 

# Imprimindo Alteração no Console
print(data)
```

Tá bem explicado, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado Cleverson, encontrei também um método split comentado abaixo.

Answer (score -1):

Solução localizada:

df['Campo1'], df['Campo2'] = df['População'].str.split('/', 1).str

del df[População]